# SonarLint with custom SonarQube F# plugin

Tags: sonarqube, sonarlint

I have created a custom plugin for SonarQube that analyzes F# code. This plugin is functioning as desired, and its results can be seen within the SonarQube UI.

I am now attempting to use SonarLint with Visual Studio by binding a solution to the one contained on my SonarQube instance. However, the F# rules are not being used when the code is analyzed via SonarLint in Visual Studio.

Does anyone have advice on getting this custom F# plugin to work with SonarLint in Visual Studio?

Comment: Is your plugin available somewhere to public?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Custom plugins are not supported in SonarLint, which is why your F# rules are not being applied.

Comment: I see, thank you! There isn't a way to override this, or expose the rules, to utilize SonarLint for my F# projects?

Comment: Sorry, there is not.